# Refresh button in ios

Tags: ios, button, refresh

How to add a refresh button in uitableview with refresh image? I have a xml data neede to be parsed in table and load the upcoming data using the offset value of the xml feed.

Comment: Are you talking about [UIRefreshControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/)?

Comment: Try this,https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @iphonic : Yeah.. I need a refresh button in map so that i can reload it!

Comment: @iphonic : but UIRefreshControl is used to set refresh action in table view so i dont need that..

Answer (score 1):

hey this is my first stack overflow answer of all time!1!

So basically use the self.tableView.reloadData() function

1. create the button in your storyboard file
2. connect it to your viewcontroller.swift file
3. create and IB action
4. execute    self.tableView.reloadData() in said function

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I understood you need to:

- Fetch new XML data
- Parse it
- Update tableView datasource
- Add a button to your view, connect it with action, smth like this:

  `- (IBAction)updateTableData:(id)sender {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
     }`

Comment: but as far as now i wish to set a refresh button in my map so that i can reload it ! but i dont know the proper coding for refresh button in map!